# UILocalNotification App in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have implemented UILocalNotifications successfully in my app. The only issue I am facing is when the app is in background and if user clears the notification. Once user open the application, app still shows badge with 1.

However I am clearing the badge with

```
 application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

on both functions didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveLocalNotification.

How can I be prompted once app comes in foreground and with all notification data.

Any help & suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: show ur didReceiveLocalNotification code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

applicationWillEnterForeground:
Tells the delegate that the application is about to enter the foreground.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
     application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is only called when app is launched. And i'm not sure didReceiveLocalNotification is called on background.

So applicationWillEnterForeground should work.

Comment: To understand MrBonjour answer, I suggest you to do a NSLog in each of methods of the AppDelegate, and see when they are called. More info there: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I agree with you Mr.Bonjour but applicationWillEnterForeground 'applicationWillEnterForeground' don't give me options to access notifications details ... So that I can access "userInfo" object and act on the notification. Will there be any way through which I can access current notification and fetch required values. Please suggest.

Comment: You will get notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and didReceiveLocalNotification

Comment: From the doc, you can consult the scheduledLocalNotifications from UIApplication. You still need to implement a custom objet in order to determine if you already done / checked the work on the last notification (scheduledLocalNotifications is an array, so it should be the first or the last index). At least you have all the data you needs

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
}
```

Method from your Apps delegate, instead of the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
}
```

Than, after your app has been reactivated, this point will be called...

Comment: Dennis as mentioned in my comment above, applicationDidBecomeActive will not be able to provide me notification data (userinfo). Please suggest if there is any way to access notification data.